# Hive on Accumulo recommended settings

Tags: hive, accumulo

We use Hive (v. 1.2.1) to read with "sql like" on accumulo (v. 1.7.1) tables.

Is there any special settings what we can configure in hive or somewhere to gain our performance or stability?

If we use the hive this way is there any point for example trying out some hive indexing or whatever settings like "hive.auto.convert.join" or it works different way and not really affect in these case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory: I wrote (most of) the AccumuloStorageHandler, but I am by no means a Hive expert.

The biggest gain you will probably be able to find is when you can structure your query in such a way that you can either prune the row-space (via a statement in the WHERE clause over the :rowid-mapped column). To my knowledge, there isn't much (any?) query optimization that is pushed down into Accumulo itself.

Depending on your workload, you could use Hive to generate your own "index tables" in Accumulo. If you can make a custom table that has the column you want to actively query stored in the Accumulo row, your queries should run much faster.